# Can not write javascript,php and css inside the virtuemart product description editor

Tags: php, joomla1.5, virtuemart

In virtuemart product description editor can not write any script and php code. I have tried with the sourcerer and DirectPHP plugin but both are not working for me. I am using Joomla1.5.23 version and the virtuemart version is 1.1.8. . Please give a solution soon.

Comment: why dont you go to com_virtuemart > view > productdetails

Comment: can't got your point. Can you please clarify the point?

Comment: you have virtuemart installed. Go to the "components/com_virtuemart/view/productdetails/tmpl". then edit the "default.php"

Comment: Sorry but under com_virtuemart there is no such folder like view. I am using Virtuemart 1.1.8 and Joomla 1.5.23.

Comment: oops sorry. I don't work with joomla 1.5 version.

Comment: But the problem is not the version of the joomla. Is there any third party plugin that can be used inside the virtuemart product description editor? I was trying to do work with joomi inside the editor but jumi is not working. Also sourcerer plugin is not working for me. I can't use DirectPHP plugin also

Comment: are you sure those plugin is compatible with your joomla version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23891/discussion-between-user734081-and-mithun-sen)